# Can Storage Spaces VirtualDisks be moved between pools?

Tags: storage-spaces

Can I move a Storage Spaces virtual disk from one pool to another?

Or do I need to create new volumes and copy the files with the operating system?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot move Storage Spaces Virtual Disk.

This is not a regular VD, but an aggregation of storage across the physical disks that comprise the pool.

Answer (score 0):

if you check the commands available from powershell then there seems to be no function to move a disk.

The best thing i can find is [New-VirtualDiskClone](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848698(v=wps.630).aspx) (i haven't tried it but it has a parameter for TargetStoragePool, i have no idea what clone means so i can't guarantee it does what i expect.)